# Is there a specific way to extend battery life in a Toshiba netbook?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, battery, power-management

I'm using Lubuntu 11.10 on a Toshiba NB-500. The new Kernel 3.0 partially solved some issues related with overheating and absence/or/unstable wi-fi connection. But I see no improvements in power management when it comes to battery life: it only lasts for 3/4 hours on Linux (7/8 hours on Windows Starter). When using Windows, the Toshiba software, mainly, the Eco Utility, are decisive to achieve those results. I wonder if anyone knows a specific trick to increase battery life on this netbook in Linux. Please note, I'm NOT looking for general tips like 'powertop', 'cpu scalling', 'screen brightness', and so on. I've tryed all that and it didn't work, so don't mark this thread as a duplicate question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are many people reporting success with Jupiter.

Features

```
Automatically adjusts CPU mode for AC or battery
Automatically tunes the kernel for AC or battery
Automatically tunes hardware for AC or battery
Supports Asus Super Hybrid Engine (SHE)
Remembers and applies last selected configuration
Fast and efficient, low resource utilization
Easily Customizable
```

> http://www.jupiterapplet.org/
>
> Jupiter: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jupiter/files/
>
> More info:
>   http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/jupiter-ubuntu-ppa-hardware-and-power.html
>
> https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/jupiter

Comment: thanks for your answer, it was sort of helpful. Here's what happened: Jupiter icon doesn't show up in Lubuntu LXDE environment.
Although this aplication is running silenghtly and it has some effect over battery life.
I believe the cpu average temperature has decreased from 46ºC to 42ºC and the battery gained a few more minutes, perhaps 15/20 minutes (not exactly what I was expecting but it better than nothing...)
More tips like this are welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a version of Jupiter that works on (L)ubuntu oneiric ocelot:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

More info: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/jupiter-applet-finally-available-for.html